# How to add a spinner for each image loading in Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, ionic-framework

**I am trying to load a list of images with spinner shown as each image is loaded.**

This is what I have but don't see how to add a spinner as each image is loaded instead of seeing a blank screen as they load

```
<div ng-repeat="i in data| filter: { tags: tag } " class='wrapper' id="homeImg">
    <!-- wrapper div -->

    <!-- image -->
    <a href="#/information"> <img class="ng-cloak" style="float:left; display:inline-block; overflow:hidden; border: 1px;" class="fill_image" src='{{ i.picture }}' style width="100%" style height="100%" ng-click="disableClick('{{ i.firebase_url }}')" /> </a>
    <!-- description div -->
    <div class='description'>
        <!-- description content -->
        <p class='description' style="float: left">
            {{i.title }}
        </p>
        <p class='description' style="float: right">
            {{i.location}}
        </p>

        <!-- end description content -->
    </div>
    <!-- end description div -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with the `||` operator inside of an `ng-src` tag:

Controller:

```
$scope.loading = "<some-pic.gif>";
```

View:

```
<!-- image -->
<a href="#/information">
    <img ng-src='{{ (i.picture) || (loading) }}'/>
</a>
```

- Change the `src` tag to `ng-src`, it is more Angular friendly
- Define a loading image/gif (previous uploaded) and store it in `$scope` variable
- Use `||` operator, if first option is `undefined` then the second (the gif) will be displayed

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xf3ezakc/

---

Also, you could use an `$ionicLoading` inside the controller to display a loading alert until **all** the images have loaded, I answered another question on how to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37750907/ionic-view-transition-flickering-issue/37752277#37752277).

```
$scope.show = function() {
    $ionicLoading.show({
        template: 'Loading...'
    }).then(function(){
        console.log("The loading indicator is now displayed");
    });
};
$scope.hide = function(){
    $ionicLoading.hide().then(function(){
        console.log("The loading indicator is now hidden");
    });
};

// Assuming you have `$scope.data`, which it seems so
$scope.data = {};
$scope.show();
someDataCall().then(function(data) {
    // success
    $scope.hide();
}).catch(error) { 
    // error
    $scope.hide();
});
```

---

I see that you also have a `firebase` reference in your code and if you are using `$firebaseArray` or `$firebaseObject` you could use `$ionicLoading` in combination with `$loaded` to detect the when the images have loaded (included in `AngularFire` API):

```
$scope.data.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    // success
    $scope.hide();
}).catch(function(error) {
    // error
    $scope.hide()
});
```

**For the last 2, make sure to have injected `$ionicLoading`**

References:

[ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc)

[$ionicLoading](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicLoading/)

[AngularFire](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire)

[ion-spinner](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionSpinner/) (I have never used it)

Comment: Hi, I never reach the second case where the loading image is shown. My page stays blank until it loads. I am interesting in finding a point where I know all images have been loaded. I look into your previous answer but I don't understand how you determined the page was finish loading

Comment: I have edited my answer, I had confused myself with `$loaded`. There are two more options to explore

Comment: Ok I see! I currently like the $ionicLoading approach with combination of using $loaded. The code now works as I was hoping, Thank you!!